# JQuery .hide() function not firing straight away in chrome and Internet explorer. works fine in firefox

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have a page that has a form

once the user submits the form I want the button to disappear and a div with a spinner gif and a validating now message to appear

so I have:

```
function submit_application(input){



    $('#create_account_button').hide();
    $('#create_account_validating').show();


    var form = $(input).parents('form:first');
    var form_id = ($(form).attr('id'));
    var valid = validate_form(form_id);

    if(valid){
        $('#'+form_id).submit();
    }


}
```

and on my form submit button I have :

```
onclick="submit_application(this);return false"
```

validate_form loops through each of the inputs and validates syntax etc.

It takes a couple of seconds to do because there are ajax calls to the server made to validate certain fields, hence the need for the 'validating now' div with the spinner gif

It all works fine in Firefox, but in Internet explorer and chrome the button never seems to disappear

Ive done some trouble shooting and realised that whats happening is those browsers validate the form BEFORE hiding and showing the relevant divs..

strange behaviour, any ideas?

Comment: Not sure why that's not working, but a possible alternative might be to make #create_account_validating big enough, and with a solid background to entirely cover the form, so that when it shows it hides the button behind it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping the validate in a delay function, like this...

```
function submit_application(input){
    $('#create_account_button').hide();
    $('#create_account_validating').show();

    setTimeout(function() {
        var form = $(input).parents('form:first');
        var form_id = ($(form).attr('id'));
        var valid = validate_form(form_id);

        if(valid){
            $('#'+form_id).submit();
        }
    }, 250);
}
```

I don't know why your code is doing what you describe, but that should solve the problem.

Comment: I found that fixes a lot of issues I've come across that I've had to just put down to different browsers, different versions, bugs & foibles.  Worth remembering - glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery's submit handler: http://api.jquery.com/submit/

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
    $('#create_account_button').hide();
    $('#create_account_validating').show();

    var valid = validate_form('myform');
    if(valid)
        $(this).submit();
    else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use callbacks?

```
function submit_application(input){    

    $('#create_account_button').hide(0, '', function(){

        $('#create_account_validating').show(0, '', function(){
            var form = $(input).parents('form:first');
            var form_id = ($(form).attr('id'));
            var valid = validate_form(form_id);

            if(valid){
                $('#'+form_id).submit();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Actually this looked like the best solution, but it added an awful transition  animation when I just wanted it to show and hide

Comment: Ah, okay. I've updated my answer with the animations disabled.